# I get the following error with new references: Package natbib Warning: Citation `dayalVariationEnglishFree2009' on page 2 unde fined on input line 65

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, undefined

I don't know why but `natbib` doesn't seem to be working. When I compile older .txt, it gives me errors. I have one file.txt which can compile the bibliography I had (which I used as a base), but the new references I inserted this week do not get compiled. I do not know why this is.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\newcommand{\squeezeup}{\vspace{-50.5mm}}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\let\olditemize\itemize
\def\itemize{\olditemize\itemsep=0pt }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}

\usepackage{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno} 

\title{A contemporary approach to \cite{vendlerEachEveryAny1962}}
\author{\vspace{-5ex}
Word-count:2887}
\date{\vspace{-4ex}}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
In this discussion note, we will provide some contemporary remarks \cite{vendlerEachEveryAny1962}. We will propose that his characterization of the Free Choice Item \textit{any} can be properly explained if we take into account an alternative semantics framework. We will assume with \cite{menendez-benitoUniversalFreeChoice2010} that it is a universal indeterminate pronoun, and with \cite{aloniFreeChoiceExhaustification2007} that it involves an \textbf{exhaustification} operator to explain its behaviour. We will show that, if we take into account this approach, we will be able to explain what Vendler called \textit{freedom of choice, lack of existential import, lawlike propositions}, among other characteristics. In addition, we will try to do some linguistics in philosophy, and try to explain how a proper understanding of FCI may help to better understand some reference related problems?
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\cite{vendlerEachEveryAny1974} intended to show that a proper linguistic analysis of quantificational expressions could help in the formalization of natural language and in understanding reference, existential import, and lawlike generalizations. He tried to show that \textit{each, every, all} and \textit{any} did not have the same universal meaning. Even though his analysis was properly linguistic, he intended to provide an empirical basis for some of the traditional problems of analytic philosophy. In this note, we will show that an alternative semantics framework can account for his insights on the Free Choice Item \textit{any}, and try to show that we can learn something about non referential expressions if we take into account the linguistic behaviour of Free Choice Items (FCI).

(...)

We have defended that reference is not at stake when FCI are taken into account, because they involve quantification. Nonetheless, we have shown that the semantics of FCI has a repercussion on the use that different speech acts involving FCI have. In the case of assertions, not only are speakers commited to the truth of the asserted propositions, but to their freedom of choice. In the case of permissions, not only is there a perlocucionary effect, but the speaker signals the hearar that she may consider any conceivable option. In the case of generic contexts, in which we did not focus, we defended that what was relevant was the relation to possible worlds and not to the actual world. Finally, all of these observations lead us to explain why Vendler noted a lack of existential import: FCI do not form referential expressions.

\bibliography{Mylibrary3}

\end{document}
```

When I compile, I get the following errors (only with the references I included this week, but in some abstracts I tried to recompile all of the references are undefined):

```
package natbib Warning: Citation `dayalVariationEnglishFree2009' on page 2 unde
fined on input line 65.
Package natbib Warning: Citation `chierchiaLogicGrammarPolarity2013' on page 2
undefined on input line 65.
[2]
Package natbib Warning: Citation `arreguiCualquierExceptionPhrases2006' on page
3 undefined on input line 93.
```

Entries of my bibfile (generated with zotero via better bibtex)

```
@article{dayalVariationEnglishFree2009,
  title = {Variation in {{English}} Free Choice Items},
  author = {Dayal, Veneeta},
  year = {2009},
  pages = {237--256},
  journal = {Universals and variation: Proceedings of GLOW in Asia VII}
}

@book{chierchiaLogicGrammarPolarity2013,
  title = {Logic in Grammar: Polarity, Free Choice, and Intervention},
  shorttitle = {Logic in Grammar},
  author = {Chierchia, Gennaro},
  year = {2013},
  edition = {First edition},
  publisher = {{Oxford University Press}},
  address = {{Oxford}},
  annotation = {OCLC: ocn827841360},
  isbn = {978-0-19-969797-7 978-0-19-969798-4},
  keywords = {Polarity (Linguistics)},
  lccn = {P299.N4 C45 2013},
  number = {2},
  series = {Oxford Studies in Semantics and Pragmatics}
}
```

Comment: Did you run `latex`+`bibtex`+`latex`+`latex`?

Comment: Yes, of course. I even tried deleting auxiliary files. I tried it in overleaf, and it still gives me error.